# VBA to exceed character limit for hyperlink in MS Excel 2010

Tags: excel, hyperlink

I am using MS Excel 2010 and I would like to create a function which allows me to concatenate several cells and construct a hyperlink that exceeds the max char limit in excel.

This post is similar ([Stackoverflow Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3893541/exceeding-max-char-limit-in-excel)) but I had several problems with the solution:

1. It used and older version of excel (not sure if this is relevant)
2. As indicated in the comments, the instructions are pretty rough (to say the least)
3. It was not clear to me if the subroutine or the function was the appropriate solution
4. I could get the subroutine code to work (but see #3) but I would really like it to be a function

Could someone clarify how to get this code to work such that it would be a function that can accept either cells or a concatenation statement ?

Thanks !

Comment: did you give it a try at least?  Give it a shot and post back, with code, what is not happening.  You may get lucky and someone here will just do it but for the most part people like to see the poster at least give it a try first.

Comment: I did give it a try - I thought I was clear in that for item number 4.  The same #VALUE error is in the cell after running the function.