# Concatenating a long hyperlink in Excel

Tags: excel

I am trying to make a customer link by concatenating two cells containing parts of the URL string, but for some reason it is not working.

These are the strings:

**A1:**
https://www.correosexpress.com/web/correosexpress/envios4?p_p_id=chxseguimientoEnviosPublico_WAR_chxseguimientoEnviosPublicoportlet&_chxseguimientoEnviosPublico_WAR_chxseguimientoEnviosPublicoportlet_struts.portlet.action=/view/getShippingPublic_execute&_chxseguimientoEnviosPublico_WAR_chxseguimientoEnviosPublicoportlet_shippingNumber=

**A2:**
(Number we will add in each custom link)

**A3:** &_chxseguimientoEnviosPublico_WAR_chxseguimientoEnviosPublicoportlet_zipCode=

**A4:** (number we will add in each customer link)

I am trying the following and receiving an error every time:

```
=HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE(A1:A2:A3:A4);[LINK])
```

I tried adding text instead of `A1` but the string is too long (more than 255 characters).

Comment: The [CONCATENATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/CONCATENATE-function-5B0392B2-94EF-49EA-8532-4FDD3A69D362) has limits. Have you tried a simpler **&** operator?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exceeding Max Char Limit in Excel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3893541/exceeding-max-char-limit-in-excel)

Answer (score 0):

I have hit the 255 character limit several times, and unfortunately there is no way around it. You can work around this with VBA, or you can shorten the url in A1 using something like goo.gl url shortener, and then concatenate.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
=HYPERLINK("CONCATENATE(A1,A2,A3,A4)","[LINK]")
```

NOTE: I put commas instead of colons and semicolons, but you may need to change them back where you are.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to send some data to a PHP-Script and i needed to work on windows and osx.
After some reasearch and trying i ended up with this visual basic function:

```
Sub SendImportData()
    Dim URL As String
    URL = "https://example.com/import.php?" & Range("M1").Value
    Open "temporary.url" For Output As #1
    Print #1, "[InternetShortcut]"
    Print #1, "URL=" & URL
    Close #1

    Shell "temporary.url"
End Sub
```

Then i built the querystring in excel itself (M1). But you can also built it within visual basic. This will give you more flexibility.
I also want to mention that you need to url-encode the values in your querystring.

There is still a limit of how long a url can be in different browsers. But its much higher than the excel limit.

Hope i could help someone.