# Adding this URL from JIRA as hyperlink to the excel cell does not work, why?

Tags: excel, vba, jira

I have the following link:

```
https://nttdata.atlassian.net/sr/jira.issueviews:searchrequest-csv-current-fields/temp/SearchRequest.csv?jqlQuery=project+%3D+ATHP+AND+issuetype+in+%28story%2C+feature%2C+task%29+AND+Sprint+%3D+1113+AND+%28status+was+not+in++%28DONE%2C+%22BUILD+COMPLETE%22%29+AFTER+%222019%2F01%2F21%22+%29+AND+%28status+was+not+in++%28DONE%2C+%22BUILD+COMPLETE%22%29++BEFORE+%222019%2F01%2F23%22%29&tempMax=1000
```

**Note:** It assumes to have an open Jira session for this project. I provided it here in case there is some special character that excel may interpret in a different way.

It executes a Jira Query and downloads the result in a CSV file.

This query is generated by JIRA when trying to export into an excel file the result of the Jira Query Language:

```
project = ATHP AND issuetype in (story, feature, task) AND 
    Sprint = 1113 AND (status was not in  (DONE, "BUILD COMPLETE") AFTER 
    "2019/01/21" ) AND (status was not in  (DONE, "BUILD COMPLETE")  
    BEFORE "2019/01/23")
```

**Note:** I was trying with a simpler query too based on JIRA request: project = ATHP (search for all issues of project with ID: ATHP) that produce the following query:

```
https://nttdata.atlassian.net/sr/jira.issueviews:searchrequest-csv-current-fields/temp/SearchRequest.csv?jqlQuery=project+%3DATHP&tempMax=1000
```

with the same result.

I added as a hyperlink to a cell and when I try to click on the cell, I get the following error:

```
Unable to open
https://nttdata.atlassian.net/...
Cannot download the information you requested
```

I thought it may be possible due to the length of the link (396 characters) that has more than 255 characters (see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3893541/exceeding-max-char-limit-in-excel)), then I created a shortened URL via Bitly, but I get the same error. If I copy and paste the URL directly in Chrome, I get the file downloaded using the original URL or the equivalent Bitly URL.

I also tried to access the hyperlink via VBA script too:

```
Range("G11").Select
Selection.Hyperlinks(1).Follow NewWindow:=False, AddHistory:=True
```

But I get the same error.

I have another similar URL created by JIRA that works well as a hyperlink:

```
https://nttdata.atlassian.net/sr/jira.issueviews:searchrequest-csv-current-fields/39627/SearchRequest-39627.csv?tempMax=1000
```

One of the differences of this URL is that instead of passing the parameters to the query (`JiraQuery`) it invokes a filter (saved query) under ID: 39627.

Any suggestion about what is going on here?, for sure there is something in the URL syntax that Excel does not like it, even the navigator accepts it.

Comment: The url returns error 400 for me

Comment: Maybe you need to login or something first. In which case please take a look at web scraping with selenium

Comment: I suspect asn error in the URL. This is what the browser returns:

HTTP Status 400 – Bad Request
The value 'ATHP' does not exsist for the field 'project
The server cannot or will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be a client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request routing).

Comment: Have you tried looking at the trust center in Excel and adding the web address to your trusted locations?

Comment: @Ricardo Diaz The URL can be accessed only if you have opened a Jira session for this project. I provided it in case there is some special character or something the excel is interpreting in a different way.

Comment: I just copied and pasted in the browser, so as @C.vanDorsten said there’s an error in the url.

Comment: @RicardoDiaz the URL looks fine outside of excel (putting it directly in Chrome), but when I add it as a hyperlink and then click on it, I got the above error. I was trying to use this URL as a way to download the file (without assigning hyperlink), but I was not able to make it works. The issue is not related with the length of the hyperlink because I got the same problem using the shortener URL. The way the URL is formed you can use it in the navigator, but not in excel as an hyperlink, but I am not able to figure it out why?

Comment: I remember having something similar. You can do some research around url encoding inside office programs

Comment: @Ricardo Diaz - No, is not the problem. I already  tried that and I got the same result.

Comment: By the way, I added a similar [question](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-questions/Why-I-cannot-use-this-URL-as-an-Hyperlink-in-excel/qaq-p/1000766#U1001635) in Altassian Jira Community, in case the solution has more to do with Jira than with Excel.