# Concatenation inside a HYPERLINK formula using email

Tags: excel, hyperlink, concatenation, powerquery

I have a sheet that concatenates various cell values (from general, text, currency and cell formats) and hard-coded strings to create an email with the mailto, subject and body pre-filled based on cell values. I have had this working but something has now broken but I still don't think there is very much wrong with what I have done.

The error I was getting was #value (error related to data being of the wrong type) but now after some edit that I must have done it now throws #name instead. The data is pulled from a row in a table that has been created from Power Query but I have pasted the code here as A1C1 references so that someone could more easily replicate it on their own version. I will plod away trying to see what I have done to break the formula. I have focused mostly on where quotation marks are but will try solving it in a blank sheet also. It may be that the cell formats are the issue but have been trying to solve this for hours!

Any help greatly appreciated!!

My formula is:
`=IF(ISBLANK(U5),"",HYPERLINK("mailto:"&AB5&"?Subject=Approval requested for project file "&LEFT(R5,LEN(R5)-5)&" - "&C5 "&body="Hi " &LEFT(H5,(FIND(" ",H5,1)-1))&", %0d%0a%0d%0aApproval of €"&U5& " for "&LEFT(R5,LEN(R5)-5)&" - "&C5&" has been granted.%0d%0a%0d%0a PO#" &T5& "%0d%0a%0d%0a Kind regards,%0d%0aSiobhán"))`

Peter

P.S. I have run this though the 'evaluate formula' wizard and the result just before it fails is below:

[Hyperlink formula just before fail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJq9h.jpg)

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think you need to add quotes around the subject title?  `...AB5&"?Subject=""Approval requested for project file """&`.  As a test, where you want the Subject text, Body text, etc, put those in actual Excel cells. Then just refer to them with a formula.  See [this page](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2688-excel-mailto-link.html) for what I mean. See how they use a cell for the subject and body text?  If that works for you, then it's just a matter of feathering that back in to the formula with quotes...

Comment: Hi, Thanks for that. I started this formula out by using the `=HYPERLINK("mailto:" & B1 & "?subject="& B2 & "&body=" & B3, "Linking text")` you refer to on that page. It just grew from there into something more difficult to see where the quotes are misplaced if that is the issue. I tried wrapping quotes around the subject title like you suggested but still get a #name error.

Comment: Quick test - just put this in a cell: `=HYPERLINK("mailto:test@example.com","Test Email")`.  Does that throw the `#NAME` error?  If not, then try `=HYPERLINK("mailto:test@example.com?Subject=Hi&body=test body","Test Email")`

Comment: Second one is fine. I will re-build it up again. I had tried using the Insert Function to help troubleshoot but all the concatenation makes it difficult to see what is the issue. Thanks very much for all your help.

Comment: Glad the second one worked, that means it's just how you're building the formula that's throwing the error and not some deeper Excel issue.  Try working "backwards" with a working formula, and piece it all together.

Comment: I do see an error here with quotes, which once you fix this I receive a #Value error instead...`&" - "&C5 &"body=Hi " &LEFT(...`

Comment: Found what it was. It was not the formula itself but rather that an actual '&' that was used in the cell value itself (In this case the value "Arts & Crafts" (which I hadn't used in my earlier testing) that when the full concatenation happens is throwing everything out of whack. If you (or any other reader) knows of how I should escape this character or convert it in some manner so that the casual user can enter an '&' in the cell without causing it to break the hyperlink please let me know.

Comment: Thanks IrwinAllen, I will note that error as well but have begun to build things up again from scratch so hopefully don't introduce the #name error again!

Comment: That makes a lot of since. You can not use the ampersand symbol in hyperlinks. I would suggest using `=Concatenate()` instead. This way you can avoid using the ampersand symbol `&`. Also, you need to clear up spaces and any other invalid characters. For example, both the space and ampersand symbols are invalid character references with hyperlinks. I would advise that you use the `=substitute()` The replacement character for spaces is `%20` while the replacement character for the ampersand is `%26`.

Comment: By the way, from what I have been reading about the `=Hyperlink` Formula, is that you have a HARD limit of how many characters this can support. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3893541/exceeding-max-char-limit-in-excel