# How to specify long body in the excel mailto formula in a CSV file?

Tags: excel, csv, mailto

Here is my CSV file:

```
Email,Values
"=HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE(""mailto:user@xyz.com?subject=X&body="", SUBSTITUTE(B2,CHAR(10),""%0d%0a"")), ""Send email"")","11231112311123111231
14562112311123111231
78292112311123111231
01233112311123111231
34543112311123111231
67834112311123111231
90154112311123111231
23465112311123111231
56765112311123111231
89066112311123111231
12376112311123111231
23487112311123111231"
```

When I open it in Excel I get this:
[image]

The problem is the length of the text in B2. Exactly the same formula with shorter content in B2 works fine:
[image]

Given that I must use a CSV file, does this issue have a solution?

Comment: Some of these links may be useful to you https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/how-do-i-do-a-hyperlink-that-exceeds-255-characters.539414/, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3893541/exceeding-max-char-limit-in-excel

Comment: I do not see how it helps. I am limited to whatever I can specify within CSV. I do not understand how can I embed my own function there.

Comment: You are limited by the hypelink function because of the character length, you can find a solution there.

Comment: I failed to find it. Please, elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the ("") double quotes are causing the issue. try this

=HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE("mailto:user@xyz.com?subject=X&body=", SUBSTITUTE(B2,CHAR(10),"%0d%0a")), "Send email")","11231112311123111231
14562112311123111231
78292112311123111231
01233112311123111231
34543112311123111231
67834112311123111231
90154112311123111231
23465112311123111231
56765112311123111231
89066112311123111231
12376112311123111231
23487112311123111231"

Comment: Have you tested it yourself?