# How to CONCAT a string to create a hyperlink with more than 255 characters

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink, concatenation

I am trying to create a direct clickable link from an excel dashboard to a SharePoint form. The link to the form takes the standard form of sharepoint.mycompany.com ... &ID=1234, with 1234 being a unique number that links to a specific form.

What I would like to do is have a simple CONCAT("address without ID","cellref with ID") Unfortunately the shortest I can make the link is 320 characters, which is over the 255 limit for Excel to process a hyperlink. I am not skilled enough with VBA to know how to structure this, and I don't know if it would make any difference if the 255 character limit is still applicable.

Comment: You can use VBA to insert hyperlinks.  Try recording a macro while using Insert >> Link and setting up an example link.  That should give you a starting point.  Beyond that, you can use (eg) an event like `Worksheet_Change` to set up your links.  Difficult to be more specific without knowing how "dynamic" those links need to be.

Comment: See previously for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3893541/exceeding-max-char-limit-in-excel

Comment: @TimWilliams the link is static except for the last 4 characters. I will try to record a macro and see where I can get from there. Thanks for the comment.